# bash file for managing public private and history of website

Tags: 14.04, command-line, server, bash, apache2

I have a website and i have 3 versions

I have the beta version with the most recent and usually not fully working changes.

I have the public site that is on www.

lastly, i have the history that I copy my old versions to when I move the beta to the public

I want to make a bash file that I run that will first copy the current public site to the "history/*current year*/*current month*/*current day*/"

then it clears out the public directory and copies the beta to the public

finally it prints that it is finished

can someone make a sample bash script for me?
i know how to create dirs and copy them and print i just need help with the current date thing

Thanks,
Ciaran

Comment: You could consider using version control system for this. git is one example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you're the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

day="$(date '+%d')"                # day=DD
moth="$(date '+%m')"               # month=MM (i.e. 04) If do you want to use it by name (i.e. April), use B ('+%B'), to use it's abbreviation (i.e. Apr), use b ('+%b). 
year="$(date '+%Y')"               # year=YYYY, if do you want YY, then use lowercase y ('+%y')
path="history/$year/$month/$day"   # path="/history/$year/$month/$day/"

cd /www                            # Change current directory to /www
echo mkdir -p "$path"                   # Create the directory.
echo mv public_html "$path"             # Move the old data to the history
echo mv beta public_html                # Rename beta to public_html
```

- Replace `/www` with your server's base path.
- Replace `public_html` with the public folder.
- Replace `beta` with your beta folder.

I've echoed all the "serious" lines. Run the program.
It will **only** echo the commands, not run them.
If all goes well, then remove all the echoes at the line begin and run again.

Comment: IMHO it is not safe to use a variable named `path`. It may easily overwrite system path (i.e., `PATH`) if the case sensitivity is not properly taken care of.

Comment: I don't mind helping out people with trouble in their scripts, but people outright demanding "make this for me" irks me a lot...  **;-)**  (not downvoted just in case someone else comes around later and gets even more irked then me...)

Comment: @Fabby: It also irks me, however I think that I can help a bit... I'm a avid vigilant of the [tag:command-line] tag. **;-)**